# Do methods that help find data in a db such as "find", "find_by", "where" etc belong in the model or controller in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've finished a personal project now just going through my code cleaning things up. I'm wondering if methods that help find things in the database belong in the model?

E.g.

This was in my controller:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(username)
```

I then moved it to my model:

```
class << self
    def find_user_by_username(username)
      User.find_by_username(username)
    end

end
```

added this to my controller:

```
@user = find_user_by_username(username)
```

Is there anything wrong with this? does it really matter if I have find, where and other methods that help find things in my controller? What about putting them in helpers?

Another thing is I tried to call that same method in a show action and pass in params with a users username as the value. I get:

```
undefined method `find_user_by_username' for #<UsersController:0x000001034a6060>
```

I just want to clean up but not break things. I don't understand why that method would work fine in my new action but not in show action.

Thanks in advance

kind regards

Comment: Ohh.. where to begin.. I'd recomend you go back to square one and read up. RubyOnRails is excellently documented. Buy a book. Take a course. Buy a screencast.
Start off by reading the guides => http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ Have fun!

Comment: Thank's I have bought every book possible. E.g. agile dev with rails, the rails way, I'm a subscriber of railscasts, I put in hours daily. It's just that my project started out as practice then turned into something I considered launching as it was a remake of a website I built using php a few years back. I'm definitely having fun though. A few months back I couldn't put together a simple sign up form. Now I've built a full community website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a good design, you want to have the skinniest controller possible, and that means moving a maximum of code from the controlelr to the model. Then, if your model become too large, there are other technique to move code down the model to other layers (libs, observers, etc).

The find_by_* method is already in the model but it his a class method. So it's perfectly reasonable to call it from your controller.

If your search was not a simple find but , let's say, a search by `user.username or user.company.name` , then you would probably have to make that search method in the model and call it from your controller.

This way also allows you to call that method from different controller instead of copy/paste-ing it

More info on where to put your code can be found here : http://qualityonrails.com/archives/33

Comment: So what I was doing was already done by rails but behind the scenes. Thanks for that link.

Comment: I hope it'll help ;)
One more thing: if you want to do class method, it's clearer to write `def self.foo...` than `class << self; def foo ...`

Comment: Thanks for your help, your response to the question I asked ryan bigg really helped.

Answer (score 1):

The controller is the *perfect* place for calls to your model's methods. It's *not* the perfect place for model logic, though.

Hint: the perfect place for that begins with 'M', ends with 'odel'.

The controller *should* call `User.find_by_username`. There should be no `find_by_username` method for the controller itself, because that's one layer of abstraction too many and "hides" what exactly the `find_by_username` method is doing.

Call the model method from your controller. You're obsessing about cleaning up when you don't need to.

Comment: So for things like updating would that go into the model? Even if I was updating a single attribute?

Comment: You must really separate the concept of what to do and how to do it. The controller asks the model to do something (what) and it "doesn't care" how the job is done (encapsulation). The model knows how to do the job but "doesn't care" whether the job has to be done. The Model defines the Business methods and the Controller calls it. A lot of Data-related business  methods are inherited or generated from ActiveRecord but that's still in the Model layer (find_by_*, update_attribute, destroy, save, where, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is perfectly fine, it is only when you starting chaining methods in the queries that you need to consider refactoring.

ie Refactoring this

`User.where(:age => 0..25).where(:owns_a_dog => true).includes(:dogs)`
into
`User.young_dog_owners`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an undefined method error is because what you defined is still a class method, so you need to call it as such:

```
@user = User.find_user_by_username(username)
```

However, you'll notice this isn't really any better than:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(username)
```

In general, my feeling is that a simple `find(id)` or `find_by_xxxx(xxxx)` is ok to have in a controller, but more advanced logic should be moved to the model. For example, if you have something like `User.where(:activated => true).where("created_at > ?", Date.today - 1.week)` you would probably want that to be moved to your `User` model under a `find_recent_users` method or something.

Comment: The strange thing is that I was able to call find_user_by_username in my new action without having to add "User." infront of it. As I would have to call User. infront of it then it would make sense to just use what I originally had.

Comment: This clears things up though. As I was refactoring I was asking myself if there was any point as it seemed to me as the code before and the code after we're no different so I might have well as just used the originally but then I remembered things I had read about keeping the controller skinny and free from database related code such as things that communicate directly with it. This is where soe confusion kicked in.